# How to delete filtered rows from Excel Table using Office Script

Tags: excel, ms-office, power-automate

I have a large excel table with over 500,000 rows. Each row contains a date column. I want to filter the rows based on the value of the date column (e.g dates within this month) and delete the resulting rows. Note that the number of rows to be deleted could be in the range of 50,000 rows. Is there a way to do this with office scripts?

I have been able to apply a dynamic date filter to filter the rows, but I cannot manage to delete only the rows that are in the VisibleView.